# Inner Joins in SOQL With Relationship

Tags: salesforce, soql

I need a help in SOQL. I am new to this, so please bear with me.

I have to do a downwards traverse in SOQL.

```
SELECT Id, (SELECT Name from Contacts WHERE CreatedDate > YESTERDAY AND LastModifiedDate >  YESTERDAY) from Account where CreatedDate > YESTERDAY AND LastModifiedDate > YESTERDAY
```

I want to get all records from Account and Contact where created date or last modified date is within a certain range. I want records where there are no changes in Account Object but changes are there in records in Contact Object.

But this query will not fetch any records if there are any changes in only Contact and no change in Account. How can I possibly do that.

Please help!

Comment: and 2 queries? one for Accounts and one for contacts.

Answer (score 0):

You're doing a [Parent-Child SOQL query](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2013/05/basic-soql-relationship-queries.html). The Contact subquery only matches Contacts associated with Accounts that match the primary query's filters.

You'll need to run one query on Account and a separate, non-relationship-based query on Contact.

Comment: I have used 2 queries, that solves my problems but unfortunately I am using these queries in Mulesoft integrations and 2 queries means establishing 2 connections to SFDC since SOQL has no UNION :(

Answer (score 0):

Probably the following answer might help someone.

Query:

SELECT Id, Name, LastModifiedDate,(SELECT Name,LastModifiedDate from Contacts WHERE LastModifiedDate >=  YESTERDAY) from Account where LastModifiedDate < YESTERDAY AND Id IN (SELECT AccountId FROM Contact WHERE LastModifiedDate >=  YESTERDAY).

Explanation:

Assuming the certain range of date is yesterday, we want to retrieve all accounts that have contacts which are modified yesterday and after yesterday but the accounts should not have been modified in the above specified range.

The above query is parent-to-child query. In the sub-query we are checking for contacts that have been modified yesterday and after that. In the outer query we are checking that accounts that might have been modified before yesterday.

Now if we stop here and do not include the IN clause the results fetched will be a outer join that is along with required results it fetches accounts that have been modified before yesterday even if they do not have a contact that has been modified yesterday or after that. See attached pic. [Outer Join results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rjilt.png)

So We have to include another check in the outer query ensuring that accounts that have contacts that have satisfied the specified date range are only returned and this is ensured using IN clause. See attached pic. [Inner Join results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ECKrl.png).

Please mark this as useful if it helps.
Thanks